# Array access not working

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
var merchants = [
    {
    "eway": 
        [{
            "transaction_fee": 0.30,
            "domestic_card_cost": 0.026,
            "plan": "Have a Go Plan",
            "link": eway_link,
            "img": '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/eway.png"/>'
        }]
    },{
    "stripe": 
        [{
            "transaction_fee": 0.30,
            "domestic_card_cost": 0.0175,
            "plan": "Standard Plan",
            "link": stripe_link,
            "img": '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/stripe.png"/>'
        }]
    }
];
```

I can access individual merchants like this:

```
var selected_merchant = "stripe";

if(value[selected_merchant]) {
    details = value[selected_merchant];
    return false;
}
```

But I fail at my next step. I am building a table with this data like this:

```
function createMerchantTable() {

    var table_row = "";

    jQuery.each(merchants, function(item, value) {

        table_row = "<tr>" +
                        "<td id='" + merchants[item] + "'>" + value[item][img] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value[item][transaction_fee] + "c</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value[item][domestic_card_cost] + "%</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

        jQuery("#merchants tbody").append(table_row);
        table_row = "";

    });

}
```

How do I access the values inside each merchant object? Thanks!

Comment: use your console to inspect what you are working with inside the `each` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this: for each outer object get its key then try to find the related attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  createMerchantTable();
});

function createMerchantTable() {

  var table_row = "";
  var merchants = [{
    "eway": [{
      "transaction_fee": 0.30,
      "domestic_card_cost": 0.026,
      "plan": "Have a Go Plan",
      "link": 'eway_link',
      "img": '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/eway.png"/>'
    }]
  }, {
    "stripe": [{
      "transaction_fee": 0.30,
      "domestic_card_cost": 0.0175,
      "plan": "Standard Plan",
      "link": 'stripe_link',
      "img": '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/stripe.png"/>'
    }]
  }];
  jQuery.each(merchants, function(index, value) {
    for (key in value) { //since your key is not fixed

      table_row = "<tr>" +
        "<td id='" + key + "'>" + value[key][0]['img'] + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + value[key][0]['transaction_fee'] + "c</td>" +
        "<td>" + value[key][0]['domestic_card_cost'] + "%</td>" +
        "</tr>";
      console.log(table_row);
      jQuery("#merchants tbody").append(table_row);
      tablke_row = "";
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="merchants">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is awesome, thanks! Only (and I corrected above) how do I get the merchant name (eway) as I loop through for the first `td` for its `id`?

Comment: @TheRealPapa  put the key as id and find the closert tr then get the id for index 0

Comment: Sorry @Suchit, I am trying to pull the merchant name in the loop you helped with, so I can place it as `id` in the `td`. I think I did not explain correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your javascript object structure, your merchants are arrays of object. So if you want to read a merchant details, you have to do this :

```
merchants.eway[0].plan;
merchants.eway[0].link;
```

You can do this with a variable and the array notation of course :

```
var merchant = 'eway';
merchants[merchant][0].link;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gc1w7b0f/)**

I believe you need to use **3 loops** to handle the `expected data format` here:

```
function createMerchantTable() {
    var table_row = "";
    $.each(merchants, function(key, value) {
        $.each(merchants[key],function(key1,value1){
            $.each(value1,function(key2,value2){
                table_row = "<tr>" +
                        "<td id=''>" + value2["img"] + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value2["transaction_fee"]+ "c</td>" +
                        "<td>" + value2["domestic_card_cost"] + "%</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                $("#merchants tbody").append(table_row);
                tablke_row = "";
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Below image explains why?

[image: Why Loop Thrice]